# when i use recursive function it returns unexpected result

Tags: java, recursion, return, zero

i've been trying to impelement rock,paper,scissor game in java.
when i try to use getinput method : the first try returns right output 1 , 2 or 3(rock,paper,scissor declared static final in gamelogic class ..)
but when i enter incorrect input then correct input it always returns 0 !

```
public int getInput(){

    System.out.println("Select ROCK , PAPER or SCISSOR");

    String choice = scanner.nextLine();

    choice = choice.toUpperCase();

    char c = choice.charAt(0);

    if(c == 'R'){
        return gameLogic.rock;
    }else if(c == 'P'){
        return gameLogic.paper;
    }else if(c == 'C'){
        return gameLogic.scissor;
    }
    getInput();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why do you use recursion for that?

Comment: The method wont exit until user enter right input

Comment: Perhaps you should **return** the value of the recursive call, i.e. `return getInput();`, instead of discarding it and returning a fixed `0`. --- Of course, in this case a *loop* would be an better solution than a recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public static int getInput(){
    int result = 0;
    System.out.println("Select ROCK , PAPER or SCISSOR");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = scanner.nextLine();

    choice = choice.toUpperCase();

    char c = choice.charAt(0);
    if(c == 'R'){
        result = 1;
    }else if(c == 'P'){
        result = 2;
    }else if(c == 'C'){
        result = 3;
    } else {
         return getInput();
    }
    return result;

}
```